# Can't create short Firebase dynamic link -> Dynamic link error 7: Forbidden

Tags: android, firebase, short, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm currently using Firebase 11.2.0 and unable to create a short dynamic link successfully

My code to create the long link is:

```
val link = "https://example.com/param/id"
val dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("v53sr.app.goo.gl")
            .setAndroidParameters(DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.greelionsoft.mareas.espana")
                    .setMinimumVersion(22)
                    .build())
            .buildDynamicLink()
```

This long link code can be shared via intent and works as expected but it's way too long.

Then the code to create shortlink:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
             .setLongLink(dynamicLink.uri)
             .buildShortDynamicLink()
             .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                 if (task.isSuccessful) {

                     val shortLink = task.result.shortLink

                     //handle shortlink
                 } else {
                     //handle error
                     Log.e("TAG", "Short Dynamic link error", task.exception)

                 }
             }
```

Task is always unsuccessful and the following error is printed in logcat:

```
Dynamic link error 7: Forbidden                                                                        
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: Forbidden
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzde.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzo.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzt.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

I haven't been able to find any clue about this "Error 7: Forbidden"

Has anybody encountered the same issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45372897/4815718.  See @IanBarber's answer. May apply here.

Comment: @BobSynder yes it seems similar but just waiting to fix itself automagically is not an ideal scenario

Comment: Maybe a [support request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) would produce a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem

1- First add your SHA256 certificate fingerprint to your Firebase Project Configuration

2- Enable "Firebase Dynamic Links API" for your project at [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com/) console

Enjoy short links!

Comment: How did you do this, I did not see where to enable Firebase Dynamic Link API on Google console?

Comment: @ValOkafor just log into console.cloud.google.com and use the search box with "Firebase Dynamic Links API" then Enable the api

Comment: Thanks, @Pablo A. Martínez I have enabled the API and still having issues. Please take a look at my question and see if there is anything that I am missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150106/firebase-dynamic-link-shorturl-not-working-in-android